# validate self signed certificate wit AFNetworking

Tags: ios, certificate, afnetworking, self-signed, general-network-error

I want to connect my iOS App with AFNetwork to my webserver with a self-signed certificate. I found a solution on github (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/694) I tried it out and the certificate pinning seems to work but i got an other error:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x7bc2090 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=(my domain)}

Does anybody know whether this error has to do with the AFNetworking Framework and the self signed certificate or not?

**Solved:**
I found the solution for the error. I had to set the SSLPinningMode to AFSSLPinningModeCertificate now it works.

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSDictionary *resDictionary = (NSDictionary *)JSON;
}
failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}];
operation.SSLPinningMode = AFSSLPinningModeCertificate;
[operation start];
```

Comment: can you show us codes? this error is generic & can be resulted from many reasons.

Comment: I don´t use any special code I only use the standard JSON Response 'AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
        [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request                                                       success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)' it is working when i set '_AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_' define to 1

Comment: added code in question for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this work around.

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSDictionary *resDictionary = (NSDictionary *)JSON;
}
                                                                                   failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                                                                       NSLog(@"%@",error);
                                                                                   }];
operation.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
[operation start];
```

Comment: Allowing invalid certificates is a terrible idea! It will stop this error but it will also make the application totally insecure.

Comment: I agree with secure layer but without a SSL certificate cannot test some web service if they use a SSL certificate. And if don't have another solution how to test a HTTPS web service without SSL certificate why give -1?

Comment: As OP’s update to the question states, the problem is solved by setting `operation.SSLPinningMode`. This completely solves the problem the OP was having, and so there is no need for such a dramatic solution as setting `allowInvalidCertificates`.

Comment: Put another way, your solution may be helpful in some debugging situations, but it is not a good answer to *this* question.